# Permitting array of arrays with strong parameters in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, strong-parameters

I have searched everywhere but does anyone know if it is possible to permit and array of arrays using strong parameters in rails? My code looks like this:

```
params.require(:resource).permit(:foo, :bar => [[:baz, :bend]])
```

This is giving me:

> ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..2))

I have also tried:

```
params.require(:resource).permit(:foo, :bar => [[]])
params.require(:resource).permit(:foo, :bar => [][])
params.require(:resource).permit(:foo, :bar => [])
```

But these all give me invalid parameter errors or do not process the parameters.

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [code](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters/blob/master/lib/action_controller/parameters.rb) I think this is not possible. you have to flatten the second level.

```
 def permit(*filters)
  params = self.class.new

  filters.each do |filter|
    case filter
    when Symbol, String
      permitted_scalar_filter(params, filter)
    when Hash then
      hash_filter(params, filter)
    end
  end

  unpermitted_parameters!(params) if self.class.action_on_unpermitted_parameters

  params.permit!
end
```

Comment: There is an open issue on rails for this now: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/23640

Answer (score -3):

Here's an example taken from [rails strong parameter Github page](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters#nested-parameters):

```
params.permit(:name, {:emails => []}, :friends => [ :name, { :family => [ :name ], :hobbies => [] }])
```

Comment: I do not think that example is an array of arrays, looks to be an array with a hash and then an array within that hash. I would use an array of hashes, however I cannot do this because the keys can be the same with the current setup I have for my project